# Is there a way to call a function when the scanner meet SPECIAL_TOKEN in JAVACC?

Tags: javacc

I'm writing a simple Verilog HDL parser using JAVACC for an Eclipse plug-in.

In this plug-in, all parameters and wires are registered in Outline view.
This feature make difficult to find desired signal in Outline view if there are lots of declations in included files.
To shorter the outline list, I want to gather parameters (and other signals) from an included file into a sub-folder.

Parser actually works in two passes, it means that all compiler derivatives are resolved first, and the resulting string are passed to the Verilog parser (JAVACC).

In this reason, the JAVACC parser can't know start and end location of included file.

To solve this problem, I added SPECIAL_TOKEN which has some include-related information.

Lexer detect SPECIAL_TOKEN correctly, however I couldn't find way to call a function of parser from SPECIAL_TOKEN's preocedure body. (Actually, it is reasonable because they are located in difference classes)

I think I could use the solution descrived last section of the page ( https://javacc.java.net/doc/tokenmanager.html ).
However, I must add such code to all occurance of regular tokens, doesn't it?
As you know, grammer of Verilog is so complex, I couldn't accept above solution.

Is there a good solution solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your parser is static, then just make the parser function static.

If the parser is not static, you could arrange for the token manager to have a pointer back to its parser.  Declare this pointer as follows

```
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS : { VerlilogParser myParser ; }
```

Then just make sure to set this field before the parser starts parsing

```
VerilogParserTokenManager tokMan = new VerilogParserTokenManager(in) ;
VerlilogParser parser = new VerlilogParser(tokMan) ;
tokMan.myParser = parser ;
parser.start() ;
```

Keep in mind that lookahead can cause the token manager to be well ahead of the parser.  Therefore you must be very careful about calling the parser from the token manager.  The way that I solved the problem of correlating post-preprocessing line numbers to pre-preprocessing line numbers and file names in C++ is that I built a table that represented the mapping from one to the other.  You can see this in https://code.google.com/p/the-teaching-machine-jhigraph-and-webwriter-plus-plus/source/browse/trunk/trunk/tm/src/tm/cpp/parser/cplusplus.jj . Here are some excerpts:

When the parser needs to know the original coords of the next token, it calls getCoords(0) defined as follows:

```
 // Coordinates
 SourceCoords getCoords(int offset ) {
     return pc.line_map.getCoords(getToken(offset).beginLine) ; }
```

The line_map table is filled by the token manager using the following code.

```
SPECIAL_TOKEN :
{
    // Line directives should have the form
    // #line linenum filename
    // or
    // #line linenum
    // In the latter case the previous file name is kept.
    "#line" : LINE_DIRECTIVE
}

<LINE_DIRECTIVE> SPECIAL_TOKEN :
{
    <LINE_NO : (["0"-"9"])+>
    { tokenLine = matchedToken.beginLine+1 ;
      sourceLine = Integer.parseInt (matchedToken.image.trim()); }
|
    <FILE_NM : "\"" (["0"-"9"])+ "\"">
    { file = fileMap.get( new Integer(matchedToken.image.substring(1, matchedToken.image.length()-1) ) );}
|
    " "
|
    "\n" { pc.line_map.add (tokenLine, sourceLine, file); } : DEFAULT
}
```